# dynamically populate dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i m using following code to populate dropdownlist dynamically...
i want that value should be the subject id and text should be the sub_desc...but code is not working the value does not contain the sub_ids...so whats wrong with the code??

**(sub_id is integer field)**

```
 public void Populate()
        {
            string ConnectionString = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand popCmd = new SqlCommand("select sub_id,sub_desc from subject", conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                ddlSub.Items.Clear();

                SqlDataReader subs;
                subs = popCmd.ExecuteReader();


                ddlSub.DataSource = subs;
                ddlSub.DataValueField = "sub_id";
                ddlSub.DataTextField = "sub_desc";
                ddlSub.DataBind();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               lblMsg.Visible = true;
               lblMsg.Text = ex.ToString();

            }

        }
```

thanx...

Comment: You have to insert the new item after dtaabinding, not before.

Comment: At what point in the Page Life cycle are you calling Populate?

Comment: i m calling this method on page load..

Comment: Are you wrapping your call to Populate in a !IsPostBack block?

Comment: You should close the connection in a finally block (or use the C# using statement). If you receive an exception while retrieving the data, the code will not close the connection.

Comment: @Pete - Good point, you should also be closing the SqlDataReader too.

Comment: @Phaedrus--no i m not using isPostback

Comment: How are you verifying the values are empty? Have you viewed the source in your web browser? The code seems OK, test your query and make sure it returns the values you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add you default after databinding.  You will need to insert at an index of 0 though rather than Add.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` to ensure data bound items do not clear manually inserted list items.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="--Select Subject--" Text="--Select Subject--" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can also accomplish this in the code behind.

```
...
dropSub.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Subject--", "0"));
dropSub.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
SqlDataReader subs;
subs = popCmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlSub.DataSource = subs;
ddlSub.DataValueField = "sub_id";
ddlSub.DataTextField = "sub_desc";
ddlSub.DataBind();
conn.Close();
...
```